# C# Select Icon from Resources as Property at Design Time

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, embedded-resource, design-time

I've written a customcontrol and i want to be able to set an Icon property in the designer. This property should give me the option to select an icon from the embedded resources, exactly like the picturebox control (property Image), but i cant seem to figure out how to achieve this.

Unfortunately there is not alot of information online about creating controls with rich design-time support, but the information that i did find was about TypeConverters, TypeEditors yet none tell me how to achieve what i want.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The only built-in UITypeEditor is IconEditor, you already got that one.  I don't think creating your own (similar to ImageEditor) is an option, Visual Studio seems to have hard-baked support for it through the notion of 'image extenders'.

Comment: Yeah i went for images instead, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after something similar `PictureBox` control, you don't need any things, try this:

```
public class SimpleImage : Control
{

    public Image Image { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Hmm thats actually exactly what i want, just need it to be an Icon. Any ideas?

Comment: Ive decided to stop my seemingly endless search and went for images instead of icons. Done! :D

Answer (score 0):

To add the icon to the control, you can deploy the control and the image file as separate files, use an image from a system control, or include the image as part of the assembly.

```
<ToolboxBitmap("c:\MyIcon.bmp")> _
   Public Class MyUserControl
      Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

       ' Code for the control.
   End Class
```

To load from Resource

```
 <ToolboxBitmap(GetType(MyNameSpace.MyUserControl),"MyIcon.bmp")> _
   Public Class MyUserControl
      Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

      ' Generate code
      ' Code for your control.
   End Class
```

Here is the Url for more details http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311315